# pandas dataframe selection every new index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im looking for a simple way to select specific values from a pandas dataframe df.

my df rows look like this: **edited to make it more clear**

```
('df_c',     index   edge_id   source   target       dist      length     offset        ep
0       0   3993733  2072680  3740467   7.400719   66.983482  50.293263  0.989106
1       0   9337850  3740467  2072680   7.400719   66.983482  16.690219  0.989106
2       0   3993735  3740467  3740468  18.257438   51.693102   0.000000  0.935507
3       0   3993736  3740467  3740470  18.257438   80.415746   0.000000  0.935507
4       0   9337852  3740468  3740467  18.257438   51.693102  51.693102  0.935507
5       0   9337853  3740470  3740467  18.257438   80.415746  80.415746  0.935507
6       0   4917163  5293212  5474940  50.474509  113.242490  47.964551  0.600775
7       0  10261280  5474940  5293212  50.474509  113.242490  65.277939  0.600775
8       1   3993733  2072680  3740467   8.627149   66.983482  56.266520  0.985225
9       1   9337850  3740467  2072680   8.627149   66.983482  10.716962  0.985225
10      1   3993735  3740467  3740468  10.319909   51.693102   9.098376  0.978925
11      1   9337852  3740468  3740467  10.319909   51.693102  42.594727  0.978925
12      1   3993736  3740467  3740470  13.757942   80.415746   0.000000  0.962851
13      1   9337853  3740470  3740467  13.757942   80.415746  80.415746  0.962851
14      1   4565277  2072680  2072681  56.667011   53.626811   5.403604  0.526118
15      1   9909394  2072681  2072680  56.667011   53.626811  48.223207  0.526118)
```

my goal is to select each row[1] (df["index"]) with a new index. So this would be df.index 0, 8,  and so on...

is there another possible way instead of iterating over the whole df and checking for a change of index on row[1] (df["index"])?

I know there is a way for selecting every n-th row like this: df.iloc[0::n, :] but the index change on row[1] (df["index"]) hasnt the always the same sequence...

Comment: ```df.loc[df[1].diff().astype(bool)]```  there is no 6404 in ur data. are u going to capture the very first col as well (6406)? also, you should reword ur question, so that it is clear/unambiguous. are u using column 1 to determine what changes? kindly fix it and make the question clear.  for future readers. I think u should fix it

Comment: you should have posted that as an answer :) i didn't realize diff did the same thing as the below....

Comment: My bad! 6406 ( column 0 ) marks the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like shift to extract a set of rows. something like

```
df[(df.column1 - df.column1.shift(1)) >= 1]
```

seems to work. Note that the shift is usually in the opposite direction of the comparison you want to do, because you're not comparing them one by one, you're creating a shifted version of the vector and then comparing the whole vector at once. To get the current and previous values aligned to compare them, you have to shift the vector *forward* to get both values on the same sample.